# How to flatten Dataframe with pandas series inside?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to flatten my dataframe. Problem is that each row contains data of pandas.core.series.Series type which I want convert to df and concat each from other rows ones. I know that there are ways to achieve that with simple one column, but following code:

```py
big_load_df = pd.concat([load_df, load_df['LoadNodes'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1).drop('LoadNodes', axis = 1)
```

gives me such output

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-ebe7fd4b7b86> in <module>
      2 # big_load_df = data.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
      3 
----> 4 big_load_df = pd.concat([load_df, load_df['LoadNodes'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1).drop('LoadNodes', axis = 1)
      5 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4355         dtype: float64
   4356         """
-> 4357         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4358 
   4359     def _reduce(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply(self)
   1041             return self.apply_str()
   1042 
-> 1043         return self.apply_standard()
   1044 
   1045     def agg(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1100                     values,
   1101                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
-> 1102                     convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1103                 )
   1104 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    353             name = ibase.maybe_extract_name(name, data, type(self))
    354 
--> 355             if is_empty_data(data) and dtype is None:
    356                 # gh-17261
    357                 warnings.warn(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/construction.py in is_empty_data(data)
    795     is_none = data is None
    796     is_list_like_without_dtype = is_list_like(data) and not hasattr(data, "dtype")
--> 797     is_simple_empty = is_list_like_without_dtype and not data
    798     return is_none or is_simple_empty
    799 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
   1537         raise ValueError(
-> 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1540         )

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know that problem is with rows of my dataframe, but what could I do?

```py
load_df
```

```py
LoadNodes
29  Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
30  Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
31  Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
32  Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
33  Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
... ...
902 Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
903 Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
904 Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
905 Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
914 Id Description Name No LoadCaseId LtbSup...
5073 rows × 1 columns
```

```py
load_df['LoadNodes'][29]
```

```py
29       Id Description  Name  No  LoadCaseId LtbSup...
29       Id Description  Name  No  LoadCaseId LtbSup...
29       Id Description  Name  No  LoadCaseId LtbSup...
29       Id Description  Name  No  LoadCaseId LtbSup...
29       Id Description  Name  No  LoadCaseId LtbSup...
29       Id Description  Name  No  LoadCaseId LtbSup...
Name: LoadNodes, dtype: object
```